# script.js doesn't load in my create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, implementation, directory-structure

I am pretty new to coding and I am currently trying to solve a challenge from *frontendmentor.io* where my task is to build an **ip-address-tracker**.

To make this task a little bit more difficult for me, I am trying to build this app with the *React framework* via *create-react-app*.

My problem is, that my Javascript file, *script.js*, somehow isn't working. I am trying to implement it via the script-tag in my *index.html*.

```
<script src="../src/script.js"></script>
```

You can also check out the directory structure, I just updated the project on GitHub.
https://github.com/bryanhain97/ip-address-tracker

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include a script in your index.html file in react you'll have to put it into the `public` folder and specify the path by using `%PUBLIC_URL%/path-to-script-relative-to-public-dir`

**EDIT:**

I just looked at your project and what you should do instead of embedding your script in `index.html` is to import it into `index.js`. You should probably export the `initMap` function and call it from `index.js`

Comment: Thank you. I moved my script into the public folder and updated the path in my index.html.

Comment: Although that will work it is not the right way to do it...moving the script to the public folder will exclude it from the bundle. And since it is not an asset of the page you should really rather use the second approach in my answer

Answer (score 0):

OK. there are a couple of things you did wrong! First of all, React outputs some useful information in the console that is not negligible in case of failure. Please look at the following image.

1. It is clear that React is complaining about a missing React import. This is because you need to

`import React from 'react'`

even in a function component. I found this mistake in two places.

2. The URL you're using in your `script.js` file is wrong. Please see the git diff over my working directory below.
3. I don't know how you want to implement all this but I think this is not done THE REACT WAY! React is a component oriented library so, Please check [some other alternatives like](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-google-maps/api) instead of doing all this in flat functions using direct connections to your DOM element. ReactDOM has some super power to be leveraged here.

I managed to get the application work on my own IP address and Google's (see the screen captures below), though I think you didn't implement it in the REACT WAY. So, keep digging!

```
[React Error Output][1]
[Git diff of my work space with the fixes][2]
[Working App on my IP Address][3]
[Working App on Google's IP Address][4]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZB72.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHqfU.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BEzI.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZENI.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you Yannick for the constructive and helpful answer. 

As a beginner, I thought that if i write a functional component in a file A and import it in file B where i got react imported, it will work. 

I will have a deeper look into ReactDOM. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: The reason I used the URL was to bypass CORS Error, because i could not fetch data from the Geolocation-API when running my application on localhost.